# how to disable fhem at Raspberry Pi boot

Tags: debian, boot, raspbian

I have installed [fhem](http://fhem.de/fhem.html) on my Raspberry pi.
Its OS is RASPBIAN Debian Wheezy.

`fhem` starts automatically after Raspberry reboot, I want to disable its auto start at init.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the /etc/rc*.d directories (there may be more than one) and remove entries like fhem.

Or try sudo update-rc.d fhem remove.